# Anyone have any information on how to create a C/C++ Path Checker on Klocwork?

Tags: klocwork, rogue-wave

I am currently creating custom checkers for our Klocwork server. But, the rougewave website does not offer any documentation about C/C++ Path checkers. They require users to email the address on this link - https://docs.roguewave.com/en/klocwork/2020/creatingccpathcheckers.

It's been a week and there is no response from them.

Any guide or current implementations of the C/C++ Path checker that I could review or any other option you can suggest? It would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a manager on the Klocwork team. Apologies for the delayed response to your request. I've reached out to the PS team and they will be contacting you shortly.

They will be able to provide the info and samples to get you going.